# How to update powerpoint table from excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code to run from excel, and then open an existing excel and powerpoint file from the c drive, and use the data in the worksheet named "Oct18" to update the FIRST table in Slide 2 of the powerpoint.

The following is the code I wrote, but somehow it doesn't work. 
May I know if anyone knows how to go about this please ?

```
Sub WriteText_toPPT_Table()
    'Add a reference to Microsoft Powerpoint 12.0 object library
    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppShp As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim ppSld As PowerPoint.slide
    Dim xlworkbook As Workbook

    Dim firstsheet As String
    Dim fileDir As String
    Dim excelFile As String


    firstsheet = "Oct18"
    'fileDir = "c:\masterpresentation.pptx"
    'excelFile = "c:\masterexcel.pptx


    '1) Open powerpoint application
    Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    ppApp.Visible = msoTrue
    Set xlworkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=excelFile)

    '2) opening an existing presentation
    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:=fileDir)
    Set exceldir = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=excelFile)
    ppPres.Slides(2).Shapes(1).Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlworkbook.Sheets(firstsheet).Cells(4, 12)
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it work properly all the way until the line that you attempt to set the table data? `ppPres.Slides(2).Shapes(1).Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlworkbook.Sheets(firstsheet).Cells(4, 12)`

Comment: Yes, it opened the ppt and excel files, but does not update the table in the powerpoint.